# PHP VS. HTML. Passing a value from html to php

Tags: php, html

I have a action.php which does some processing involving a MySQL-Database. In action.php I generate a variable

```
$author
```

with a string in it. When the script terminates it calls test.php by

```
header('Location: ../test.php');
```

Now while test.html is shown, I want to display the content of the stringvariable

```
$author
```

in a html-element. Like

```
<h2>echo $author;</h2>
```

How do I achieve that? Thank you for any responses in advance.

Comment: Can you post exactly how you are displaying test.html? I'm not sure what you mean by "it calls test.html".

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @TaylorOtwell Thanks for replying. I edited the part you asked for. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @Capsule test.php Sorry for type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the contents of the $author in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php):

```
<?php
// action.php
session_start();
// Your code here

$_SESSION['author'] = $author;

// Redirect to test.php

<?php
// test.php
session_start();

echo '<h2>'. $_SESSION['author'] .'</h2>';
```

See:

1. [session_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: You saved my day. Didn't thought, that sessions were so easy to deal with. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you could store $author in a session variable or on the action.php page output a form with a hidden input with the value of $author and then submit it to test.php

to use session variables don't forget session_start(); and then $_SESSION['author'] = $author

Answer (score 1):

In your action.php save your variable in session like this: `$_SESSION['author'] = $author;`

Then, in your test.php file you can use `<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['author']; ?></h2>`

Don't forget to start both .php files with calling `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

Use a template engine, e.g. [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/).

While you can use PHP itself as a template engine (`include()` your file and use `<?=$var?>` or `<?php echo $var; ?>` in it), using a real template engine is usually nicer as you won't even think about moving actual business logic into your templates when you have a good template engine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either store the value of `$author` in `$_SESSION` or in a cookie.

See [session.php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Yes but be careful, you can't send a Set-cookie AND a Location header in the same batch so the session should be started in a script before the one sending the Location header.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to pull author data from a database and display it in test.php.  If so there is no need to "pass" the data to test.php, just grab data in test.php.

test.php

```
<?php
// Open DB handle
// Do query, get results.
// Store results in array ($aRes)
// Close DB handle
?>

<html>
.
.
.
  <body>
  <h2><?php echo $aRes['author'];?></h2>
  .
  .
  </body>
</html>
```

That is a very basic and obviously fairly pseudo template but hopefully it will give you a better idea of the relationship between server-side data and HTML.